# Can I copy options (everything shown when I run `:set` with no arguments) between active windows

Tags: vim-windows, options, set

I have two windows opened in the same terminal. These are actual vim windows within the same vim instance. The first window is a `.py` file which has many options set by default, plus additional options that I've set manually. The second window was opened using `ctrl-w n` which doesn't carry *any* of the settings from the original window with it. Is there a way to transfer the settings between windows?

In case it makes a difference, this is my version info:

> VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Apr 15 2020 06:40:31)
> Included patches: 1-2269

Comment: You could in theory write a loop to copy all options between two windows. Simpler is to create a script that sets the options and arrange for it to run for relevant files (typically, via an ftplugin or autocommand).

Comment: I vote to put the relevant options in rc via autocommand.

Answer (score 1):

An option can be buffer-local, window-local, or global.

Global options are, well… `global`, so they are valid globally unless overridden localy.

Window-local options only have effect in the current window and any new window split from it. `<C-w>n` splits the current window so all window-local options set in the current window are carried over to the new window.

Buffer-local options only apply to the current buffer.

If the options you set in the current window don't carry over to the new window, it might be because…

- Those options are not window-local but buffer-local, so there is no reason to expect them to be carried over to the new window.
- Some autocommand may reset those options for some reason or another.

Without knowing what *exact* options you have set, I would put my money on the first reason.

Answer (score 0):

In continuation of Romain's answer with whom I agree on the analysis of the issue at hand.

Expecting the global options are already carried over by nature, that window-local options should be carried over automatically when spawning a new window. What's left are the buffer-local options.

IMO, if you want to copy options related to Python buffer, the best is quite certainly to set the filetype of the new buffer to ... python

```
set ft=python
```

But still, a few options will be left out:

- the ones you have set  manually (IMO, this practice is best avoided. Prefer automated way to set options)
- the ones that may come from a plugin emulating local .vimrc support, or any kind of projects. Usually these plugins are activated when the name of the new buffer matches a given pattern. The new window has no associated name. A workaround would be: `:vnew %:p:h/new-dummy-name.py`. Just don't save the new buffer...

---

Otherwise, while it's IMO the wrong approach to the problem, it's possible to request:

- all window-local options (from the current window) with `getwinvar('%', '&')`
- all buffer-local options (from the current buffer) with `getbufvar('%', '&')`

Then, you'll need to iterate on the resulting dictionary and call `setwinvar`/`setbufvar` of each dictionary item. Dirty, and faster, one-liners are possible  with `map()`